# How can I create custom loss function in Keras which is different for each sample

Tags: python, keras, loss

I have e.g. 100 samples (100 outputs). I would like to write custom loss function with a "weight" for each sample:

```
(target[j] - prediction[j])**2 + f(j),
```

Where f is a custom numeric function (e.g. `j**2`). How can I do this
Now I am only able to create "universal" loss function (without "weights"):

```
def customloss(target,prediction):
   return (target - prediction)**2
```

The problem is I cannot get the index (j).

Comment: Why dont you add an extra parameter `weight`? A vector with the weight for each sample.

Comment: The problem is AFAIK weights can only multiply results, so I would get sth like that: (target[j] - prediction[j])**2 * f(j) and I would like to add "weights" instead of multiply by them

Answer (score 0):

This might not be further relevant, but you can create a second network with an Input Layer. Towards that Input Layer you pass an Array that represents your weights.

Now wrap your model:

```
weight_layer = Input(shape=(None,dim))
m2 = Model(input=[m1.inputs,weight_layer],output=m1.outputs)
```

Since the output of a loss functions is also a Tensor you can add the weight_layer to your loss.
e.g.:

```
def customloss(y_true,y_pred):
    return K.binary_crossentropy(y_true,y_pred) + weight_layer
m2.compile(optimizer='adam',loss=customloss,...)
```